# SQL Server 2012 Collapsing into minimum rows failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I am trying to create a time series to track changes for financial securities over time from a security changes audit table `AdvApp.vSecurity_Hist h`. I want to see only rows with the MIN date for unique security identifiers which are Symbol, ISIN, SEDOL, CUSIP. I only want to see rows where any one of these have changes. These change are due to corporate reorganizations but the System generated SecurityID doesn't change. I only want changes in the other columns per distinct Security ID Here is an example of a security that legitimately changed 3 times and the date it changed. No problem with the query result here.

Legit time series with changes.

Note if there are multiple changes on the same day then the row with the Max time is the one that's selected. I am looking for daily changes, not intraday changes.

```
SecurityID  MinDate CUSIP   ISIN    SEDOL   Symbol  SecurityCount
5156    2011-10-22  61745P635           iqc 3
5156    2012-01-31  46130M107           iqc 3
5156    2012-09-12  46130m107           iqcoldx 3
```

Here is an example from the raw data of a problematic time series that is breaking my query. Note row 10 is missing a value in the CUSIP field, sometimes it's legitimate that there is no CUSIP but the rule is if the same CUSIP value precedes and succeeds the blank field, then the blank field is not legitimate and should be filled in with the preceding and succeeding values in that field. As you can see the CUSIP values resume in row 11.

Problem Set from raw data

```
SecurityID  CUSIP   ISIN    SEDOL   Symbol  OptionSymbol    AuditEventTime
5060    233809201           fduxx       2011-10-22 00:12:31.310
5060    233809201           fduxx       2012-03-21 19:33:41.387
5060    233809201           fduxx       2012-03-21 21:40:05.813
5060    233809201           fduxx       2012-03-30 15:00:45.243
5060    233809201           fduxx       2012-04-04 11:31:59.280
5060    233809201           fduxx       2012-05-15 09:19:38.360
5060    233809201           fduxx       2012-05-15 10:04:10.597
5060    233809201           fduxx       2012-07-03 15:54:41.043
5060    233809201           fduxx       2013-04-04 18:25:27.253
5060                fduxx       2013-09-26 09:45:00.137
5060    233809201           fduxx       2013-10-01 13:03:59.277
5060    233809201           fduxx       2016-12-02 18:52:53.093
5060    233809201           fduxx       2017-10-06 08:43:58.717
```

Here is the result of my query based on this problematic data. The query is looking to group on the min date of the change so it picks up row 1 and row 9 but then ignores rows 11-13 which is causing some issues.

Query Result.

Based on my rules I don't want the second row with the blank CUSIP field because the rows that precede and succeed it have matching values in all fields.

```
SecurityID  MinDate CUSIP   ISIN    SEDOL   Symbol  SecurityCount
5060    2011-10-22  233809201           fduxx   2
5060    2013-09-26              fduxx   2
```

I am thinking about utilizing logic using lead and lag where if there is a blank row but the led and lag values matches each other (excluding the time) then place the lead CUSIP value in the blank row. That would then let me collapse the dataset with SecurityID 5060 into one row. I think to do this I need to change my partition or my query so that it recognizes the final rows 11-13 is actually a third series. Right now the final rows are being ignored because the values match the data that precedes the blank and thus are not the min date of that set. Here is my SQL Query. I'd like to know the following:

```
1)How can I make the query result produce three rows for SecurityID 5060? (Make it consider the data that comes after the blank as it's own row)
2)where and how in the query should I then apply Lead and Lag to help fill in the blank and then collapse the result into a single row?
```

Thank you

My current Query

```
WITH DATA AS
(
SELECT 
b.SecurityID,
MIN(b.AuditEventDate)MinDate,
b.CUSIP,
b.ISIN,
b.SEDOL,
b.Symbol,
COUNT(b.SecurityID) OVER (PARTITION BY b.SecurityID)SecurityCount
FROM
(
SELECT a.*,
MAX(a.AuditEventTime) OVER (PARTITION BY a.SecurityID,a.AuditEventDate) MaxTime
FROM
(
SELECT distinct
h.SecurityID
,h.AuditEventTime
,CAST(h.AuditEventTime AS DATE)AuditEventDate
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(h.OptionSymbol,'') <> '' THEN h.OptionSymbol ELSE h.Symbol END Symbol
,h.CUSIP
,h.SEDOL
,h.ISIN
FROM APXFirm.AdvApp.vSecurity_Hist h
WHERE 1 = 1
AND (LEN(h.CUSIP) = 9 OR ISNULL(h.CUSIP,'') = '')
AND (LEN(h.SEDOL) = 7 OR ISNULL(h.SEDOL,'') = '') 
AND (LEN(h.ISIN) = 12 OR ISNULL(h.ISIN,'') = '') 
AND h.SecurityID = 5060
)a
)b
WHERE b.AuditEventTime = b.MaxTime
GROUP BY b.SecurityID,
         b.CUSIP,
         b.ISIN,
         b.SEDOL,
         b.Symbol
)
SELECT * FROM Data 
WHERE DATA.SecurityCount > 1
ORDER BY Data.SecurityID,MINDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to "fix" that NULL value at the source (as early as possible) otherwise you don't have reliable "previous/following" row relationships available after grouping e.g.

```
  SELECT
        b.SecurityID
      , MIN(b.AuditEventDate)                                mindate
      , b.CUSIP
      , b.ISIN
      , b.SEDOL
      , b.Symbol
      , COUNT(b.SecurityID) OVER (PARTITION BY b.SecurityID) securitycount
  FROM (
        SELECT
              a.*
            , MAX(a.AuditEventTime) OVER (PARTITION BY a.SecurityID, a.AuditEventDate) maxtime
        FROM (
              SELECT DISTINCT /* but I doubt that distinct does anything useful */
                    h.SecurityID
                  , h.AuditEventTime
                  , CAST(h.AuditEventTime AS date)                                                   auditeventdate
                  , CASE WHEN ISNULL(h.OptionSymbol, '') <> '' THEN h.OptionSymbol ELSE h.Symbol END symbol
                  , case when h.CUSIP IS NULL and  lag(h.CUSIP,1) over(order by AuditEventTime)
                                               =  lead(h.CUSIP,1) over(order by AuditEventTime)
                         then lead(h.CUSIP,1) over(order by AuditEventTime)
                         else h.CUSIP
                    end as CUSIP
                  , h.SEDOL
                  , h.ISIN
              FROM vSecurity_Hist h
              /* where clause needed here */
        ) a
  ) b
  WHERE b.AuditEventTime = b.MaxTime
  GROUP BY
        b.SecurityID
      , b.CUSIP
      , b.ISIN
      , b.SEDOL
      , b.Symbol
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a07b6/5)

Comment: Checking it out now.

Comment: Looks like it's working. I had to add securityID in addition to AuditEventTime in the order by for Lead and Lag due to the fact in reality there are many securities in the data. Also in the data CUSIP actually = '' not NULL but that was an easy fix.